# How to make a HTML video pause/play on mobile using javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, onclick

(BRAND new to javascript) I have created a simple play/pause button but will only work on desktop. Can i make a simple alteration to code to make the button work on mobile?

I have tried to swap out the .onclick event with .ontouchstart but it will not work on iphone

```
            <script>
            var video = document.querySelector('.video');
            var btn = document.getElementById('play-pause');

            function togglePlayPause() {
                if(video.paused) {
                    btn.className = "pauseButton";
                    video.play();
                }
                else {
                    btn.className = "playButton";
                    video.pause();
                }
            }

            btn.onclick = function() {
                togglePlayPause ();
            };


            </script>
```

I expect the video to pause but does nothing when clicking on mobile

Answer (score 2):

Try registering an event listener to the button according to the touch support:

```js
// Check touch support
let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

var video = document.querySelector('.video');
var btn = document.getElementById('play-pause');

function togglePlayPause() {
    if(video.paused) {
        btn.className = "pauseButton";
        video.play();
    } else {
        btn.className = "playButton";
        video.pause();
    }
}

// Bind event
btn.addEventListener(touchEvent, togglePlayPause);
```

**Update**

I've put my snippet in your code

Comment: Where would I put the                   `let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';`
 within the code? Sorry i'm very helpless